# Add Auth token for spring web socket

Tags: java, spring-security, stomp, spring-websocket

I'm implementing a simple socket like this :

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
}
```

From the client-side :

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

And the websocket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
}
```

}

Now I would like to apply authentication for the socket so that not all clients can connect to server. I may look like

```
var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket?token= a JWT token'); //or sth similar
```

from the client-side.

Let just assume that I can hide the token from people who inspect the frontend code, how do I get that token and verify it from the server side ? (Provided that I have the function to verify the JWT already)

Or is there any better way of implementing security for socket connection that you can suggest ?

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.